# SQL Server CASE query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it may sound very small issue but need to resolve, following is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN A.ReleaseDate = '1900-01-01' THEN '' 
       WHEN A.ReleaseDate IS NULL THEN '' 
       ELSE ReleaseDate 
    END AS ReleaseDate 
FROM XYZ
```

I can see `Releasedate` is `1900-01-01` in my table but still case is using `ELSE` condition. I can't find out the reason.

Comment: The field being output should be consistent. i.e. In one case you are returning '' (which is varchar) and in another you are returning the date, which is not ok. It is like a function returning different type in each of its conditions.

Comment: What datatype is the ReleaseDate field? The thing is no one asked that yet. What if your ReleaseDate field is a datetime and by not adding the time portion in that when is never being realized? Not disputing what anyone is saying but its just that the datatype of the ReleaseDate field has in fact not been confirmed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single type.  I think yours will return a date.  Hence you get a date and a blank string turns into some very old date.

If you want it to return a blank string, then you want a string back.  So use explicit conversion:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN A.ReleaseDate = '1900-01-01' THEN '' 
             WHEN A.ReleaseDate is null THEN '' 
             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReleaseDate, 121)
         END) as ReleaseDate 
FROM XYZ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your ReleaseDate as Varchar

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ReleaseDate = '1900-01-01' THEN '' 
             WHEN ReleaseDate is null THEN '' 
             ELSE cast(ReleaseDate as varchar)
         END) as ReleaseDate 
FROM XYZ;
```

Comment: This is the same answer as Gordon's, except you have varchar with no size defined. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length